# CABasicAnimation keys

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to know what are all the possible keys used in `CABasicAnimation`

like this one:

```
CABasicAnimation *imageRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
```

which makes a rotation ... where can I find all possible keys?
and thanks in forward

Comment: thats what i'm doing now .. thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230796/what-is-the-full-keypath-list-for-cabasicanimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered looking up the class reference for CABasicAnimation, and its corresponding super classes?

CABasicAnimation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

CAPropertyAnimation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAPropertyAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAPropertyAnimation

CAAnimation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAAnimation

Comment: I don't see a concrete list of supported key paths for animation at all.

Comment: These pages do not provide the list for possible keyPath values.

Comment: I am unable to find a list of these key paths on the pages linked. Maybe I am not navigating those pages correctly. If you can find a list and update the answer I'd appreciate it and give an upvote.

Answer (score 23):

The following is the major `animationWithKeyPath` values.

[image: animationWithKeyPath]

Reference http://www.adamzucchi.com/blog/?p=24

Answer (score 9):

This source is mentioned in a comment on one of the answers, but in the hope that this can be accepted for those in the future who find this question, the correct list as of the date this is posted is this page on apple's docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html

Here are the keypaths listed in those links:

(Unless otherwise noted, CALayer properties use the default CABasicAnimation)

#### CALayer

- **anchorPoint**: *CGPoint*
- **backgroundColor**: *CGColor?*
- **backgroundFilters**: *[CIFilter]?* (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
- **borderColor**: *CGColor?*
- **borderWidth**: *CGFloat*
- **bounds**: *CGRect*
- **compositingFilter**: *CIFilter?* (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
- **contents**: *CGImage?*
- **contentsRect**: *CGRect*
- **cornerRadius**: *CGFloat*
- **doubleSided**: *Bool* (no default animation)
- **filters**: __[CIFilter]? (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
- **frame**: *CGRect* (!!not animatable!! use bounds and position)
- **hidden**: *Bool*
- **mask**: *CALayer?*
- **masksToBounds**: *Bool*
- **opacity**: *Float* (0 <= opacity <= 1)
- **position**: *CGPoint*
- **shadowColor**: *CGColor?*
- **shadowOffset**: *CGSize* (default is (0,-3))
- **shadowOpacity**: *Float* (0 <= shadowOpacity <= 1)
- **shadowPath**: *CGPath?*
- **shadowRadius**: *CGFloat* (default is 3)
- **sublayers**: *[CALayer]?*
- **sublayerTransform**: *CATransform3D*
- **transform**: *CATransform3D*
- **zPosition**: *CGFloat*

CALayer default implied CABasicAnimation**: *duration* = 0.25s or duration of current transaction.
CALayer default implied CATransition**: *duration* = 0.25s or duration of current transaction, type = kCATransitionFade, start progress = 0, end progress = 1

#### CIFilter (macOS only)

- **name**: *String*
- **enabled**: *Bool*

#### CATransform3D

- **rotation.x**: *NSNumber* (radians)
- **rotation.y**: *NSNumber* (radians)
- **rotation.z**: *NSNumber* (radians)
- **rotation**: *NSNumber* (radians) (identical to rotation.z)
- **scale.x**: *NSNumber*
- **scale.y**: *NSNumber*
- **scale.z**: *NSNumber*
- **scale**: *NSNumber* (average of all three scale factors)
- **translation.x**: *NSNumber*
- **translation.y**: *NSNumber*
- **translation.z**: *NSNumber*
- **translation**: *NSValue* containing an NSSize or CGSize

#### CGPoint

- **x**: *CGFloat*
- **y**: *CGFloat*

#### CGSize

- **width**: *CGFloat*
- **height**: *CGFloat*

#### CGRect

- **origin**: *CGPoint*
- **origin.x**: *CGFloat*
- **origin.y**: *CGFloat*
- **size**: *CGSize*
- **size.width**: *CGFloat*
- **size.height**: *CGFloat*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19550614)

Comment: @juanjo Fixed. Still getting a hang of participating on Stack Overflow after quite a while of being a lurker :)

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

**You may simply** write: CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.strokeColor))

Also, use command+shift+o, open, for example, CALayer.h and watch a comments. **Apple team provides information about animatable feature

for animatable keys:

==== **Pretty Wrapper; Usage example** ====

*Please reply this message about incorrectness, if u'll see*

```
extension CABasicAnimation {
        convenience init(_ key: CAPropertyAnimation.Key, duration: Double) {
        self.init(keyPath: key.keyPath)
        self.duration = duration
    }
}
```

[image: XCode look]

---

```
extension CAPropertyAnimation {

    enum Key {

        /// `CALayer` in the `Parent` layer for `Subclass layers`.  Able to use this keys for animating `Subclass layers`
        case caLayer(_ property: CALayer.CALayerAnimatableProperty)
        case shapeLayer(_ property: CAShapeLayer.AnimatableProperty)
        case emitterLayer(_ property: CAEmitterLayer.AnimatableProperty)
        case gradientLayer(_ property: CAGradientLayer.AnimatableProperty)
        case replicationLayer(_ property: CAReplicatorLayer.AnimatableProperty)
        case textLayer(_ property: CATextLayer.AnimatableProperty)

        var keyPath: String {
            switch self {
            case .caLayer(let property):           return property.rawValue
            case .shapeLayer(let property):        return property.rawValue
            case .emitterLayer(let property):      return property.rawValue
            case .gradientLayer(let property):     return property.rawValue
            case .replicationLayer(let property):  return property.rawValue
            case .textLayer(let property):         return property.rawValue
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CALayer {

    /**

     - references:

     [Apple. Key-Value Coding Extensions (CALayer examples)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW2)

     [Apple. Animatable Properties.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)

     [Stack overflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230796/what-is-the-full-keypath-list-for-cabasicanimation)

     [Stack overflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913101/cabasicanimation-keys)

     */

    enum CALayerAnimatableProperty: String {

        /// CGPoint
        case anchorPoint = "anchorPoint"
        /// CGPoint
        case anchorPointZ = "anchorPointZ"
        /// CGColor?
        case backgroundColor = "backgroundColor"
        /// [CIFilter]? (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
        case backgroundFilters = "backgroundFilters"
        /// CGColor?
        case borderColor = "borderColor"
        /// CGFloat
        case borderWidth = "borderWidth"
        /// CGRect
        case bounds = "bounds"
        /// CGpoint
        case boundsOrigin = "bounds.origin"
        /// CGFloat
        case boundsOriginX = "bounds.origin.x"
        /// CGFloat
        case boundsOriginY = "bounds.origin.y"
        /// CGSize
        case boundsSize = "bounds.size"
        /// CGFloat
        case boundsWidth = "bounds.size.width"
        /// CGFloat
        case boundsHeight = "bounds.size.height"
        /// CIFilter? (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
        case compositingFilter = "compositingFilter"
        /// typically a CGImageRef, but may be something else
        case contents = "contents"
        /// CGRect
        case contentsRect = "contentsRect"
        /// CGFloat
        case contentsScale = "contentsScale"
        /// CGRect
        case contentsCenter = "contentsCenter"
        /// CGFloat
        case cornerRadius = "cornerRadius"
        /// Bool (no default animation)
        case doubleSided = "doubleSided"
        /// [CIFilter]? (uses default CATransition, sub-properties of filters are animated using default CABasicAnimation)
        case filters = "filters"
        /// CGRect (!!not animatable!! use bounds and position)
        case frame = "frame"
        /// Bool
        case hidden = "hidden"
        /// Bool
        case masksToBounds = "masksToBounds"
        /// Float
        case minificationFilterBias = "minificationFilterBias"
        /// Float (0 <= opacity <= 1)
        case opacity = "opacity"
        /// CGPoint
        case position = "position"
        /// CGFloat
        case positionX = "position.x"
        /// CGFloat
        case positionY = "position.y"
        /// CGFloat
        case rotationX = "transform.rotation.x"
        /// CGFloat
        case rotationY = "transform.rotation.y"
        /// CGFloat
        case rotationZ = "transform.rotation.z"
        /// CGFloat
        case scale = "transform.scale"
        /// CGFloat
        case scaleX = "transform.scale.x"
        /// CGFloat
        case scaleY = "transform.scale.y"
        /// CGFloat
        case scaleZ = "transform.scale.z"
        /// CGColor?
        case shadowColor = "shadowColor"
        /// CGSize (default is (0,-3))
        case shadowOffset = "shadowOffset"
        /// Float (0 <= shadowOpacity <= 1); default is 0
        case shadowOpacity = "shadowOpacity"
        /// CGpath?
        case shadowPath = "shadowPath"
        /// CGFloat (default is 3)
        case shadowRadius = "shadowRadius"
        /// [CALayer]?
        case sublayers = "sublayers"
        /// Bool
        case shouldRasterize = "shouldRasterize"
        /// CGFloat
        case rasterizationScale = "rasterizationScale"
        /// CATransform3D
        case sublayerTransform = "sublayerTransform"
        /// CGSize
        case translation = "transform.translation"
        /// CGFloat
        case translationX = "transform.translation.x"
        /// CGFloat
        case translationY = "transform.translation.y"
        /// CGFloat
        case translationZ = "transform.translation.z"
        /// CATransform3D
        case transform = "transform"
        /// CGFloat
        case zPosition = "zPosition"
    }
}

extension CAShapeLayer {

    enum AnimatableProperty: String {
        /// CGColor?
        case fillColor = "fillColor"
        /// [NSNumber]?
        case lineDashPhase = "lineDashPhase"
        /// CGFloat
        case lineWidth = "lineWidth"
        /// CGFloat
        case miterLimit = "miterLimit"
        /// CGColor?
        case strokeColor = "strokeColor"
        /// CGFloat
        case strokeStart = "strokeStart"
        /// CGFloat
        case strokeEnd = "strokeEnd"
    }
}

extension CAEmitterLayer {

    enum AnimatableProperty: String {

        /// CGPoint
        case emitterPosition = "emitterPosition"
        /// CGFloat
        case emitterZPosition = "emitterZPosition"
        /// CGSize
        case emitterSize = "emitterSize"
    }
}

extension CAGradientLayer {

    enum AnimatableProperty: String {

        /// [CGColor]? ([Any]? by Apple docs, but CGColor works as well)
        case colors = "colors"
        /// [NSNuber]?
        case locations = "locations"
        /// CGPoint
        case endPoint = "endPoint"
        /// CGPoint
        case startPoint = "startPoint"
    }

}

extension CAReplicatorLayer {

    enum AnimatableProperty: String {

        /// CFTimeInterval (Double)
        case instanceDelay = "instanceDelay"
        /// CATransform3D
        case instanceTransform = "instanceTransform"
        /// Float
        case instanceRedOffset = "instanceRedOffset"
        /// Float
        case instanceGreenOffset = "instanceGreenOffset"
        /// Float
        case instanceBlueOffset = "instanceBlueOffset"
        /// Float
        case instanceAlphaOffset = "instanceAlphaOffset"
    }
}

extension CATextLayer {

    enum AnimatableProperty: String {

        /// CGSize
        case fontSize = "fontSize"
        /// CGColor?
        case foregroundColor = "foregroundColor"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find them in ["Key Path Support for Structure Fields"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html) section of CoreAnimation programming guide

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use every possible **keyPath**.
So if an object implements the property 'alpha', like all views do, you can let this property animate automatically.

The CAAnimation then calculates steps between the start point, and the end point of the animation, sets them and redraws the view.

Comment: This link is dead now :(

Comment: @Lewis42 There is no link in my answer ;)