# What is the full Keypath list for CABasicAnimation?

Tags: core-animation

I've looked in the documentation but I noticed it's missing some like "transform.scale.xy": [CoreAnimation Guide][1] is there a more complete list?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Here's everything I'm aware of in terms of animatable properties, keyPaths,  and key-value coding extensions.

**CALayer** Animatable layer properties -- the other CALayer types below all inherit from CALayer, so these also apply to those:

```
anchorPoint
backgroundColor
backgroundFilters
borderColor
borderWidth
bounds
compositingFilter
contents
contentsRect
cornerRadius
doubleSided
filters
frame
hidden
mask
masksToBounds
opacity
position
shadowColor
shadowOffset
shadowOpacity
shadowPath
shadowRadius
sublayers
sublayerTransform
transform
zPosition
```

**CAEmitterLayer** animatable properties:

```
emitterPosition
emitterZPosition
emitterSize
```

**CAGradientLayer** animatable properties:

```
colors
locations
endPoint
startPoint
```

**CAReplicatorLayer** animatable properties:

```
instanceDelay
instanceTransform
instanceRedOffset
instanceGreenOffset
instanceBlueOffset
instanceAlphaOffset
```

**CAShapeLayer** animatable properties:

```
fillColor
lineDashPhase
lineWidth
miterLimit
strokeColor
strokeStart
strokeEnd
```

**CATextLayer** animatable properties:

```
fontSize
foregroundColor
```

**CATiledLayer** animatable properties:

```
I feel like tileSize is animatable, but documentation doesn't agree.
```

**CATransform3D** Key-Value Coding Extensions:

```
rotation.x
rotation.y
rotation.z
rotation
scale.x
scale.y
scale.z
scale
translation.x
translation.y
translation.z
```

**CGPoint** keyPaths:

```
x
y
```

**CGSize** keyPaths:

```
width
height
```

**CGRect** keyPaths:

```
origin
origin.x
origin.y
size
size.width
size.height
```

These are **[Appendix B](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)** of the **[Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH1-SW1)**, and **[Appendix C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW2)** of the same.