# How to animate a UIViews 'center' property?

Tags: ios, core-animation

As I read here in the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview?language=objc) I'm able to animate the 'center' property of a `UIView`.

I'm using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to do that and provide this animation three Keyframes and three CGPoints.

The animation seems not to work. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
NSMutableArray* values = [NSMutableArray new];
[values addObject:@(CGPointMake(0, 0))];
[values addObject:@(CGPointMake(5, 8))];
[values addObject:@(CGPointMake(10, 8))];

NSMutableArray* keyTimes = [NSMutableArray new];
[keyTimes addObject:@(0)];
[keyTimes addObject:@(0.5)];
[keyTimes addObject:@(1)];

NSMutableArray* timingFunctions = [NSMutableArray new];
[timingFunctions addObject:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
[timingFunctions addObject:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

CAKeyframeAnimation* myAimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"center"];
myAimation.duration             = 0.5;
myAimation.values               = values;
myAimation.timingFunctions      = timingFunctions;
myAimation.keyTimes             = keyTimes;

[myView.layer addAnimation:myAimation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because`center` is not the property of `CALayer`.

You can check full list from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230796/what-is-the-full-keypath-list-for-cabasicanimation/49480213#49480213)

You can also read it from apple site: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW1

try `[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing keypath from "center" to "position"
My swift code is working with this

```
    func animate() {
    var values: [AnyHashable] = []
    values.append(NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)))
    values.append(NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 140)))
    values.append(NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 200)))

    var keyTimes: [NSNumber] = []
    keyTimes.append(NSNumber(value: 0))
    keyTimes.append(NSNumber(value: 0.5))
    keyTimes.append(NSNumber(value: 1))

    var timingFunctions: [AnyHashable] = []
    timingFunctions.append(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut))
    timingFunctions.append(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut))

    let myAimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    myAimation.duration = 0.5
    myAimation.values = values
    myAimation.timingFunctions = timingFunctions as? [CAMediaTimingFunction]
    myAimation.keyTimes = keyTimes       
    myView.layer.add(myAimation, forKey: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint I'll try `position`. But why is `center` mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Center is written to say that we can move the object by simply changing the center without changing its frame , origin or bounds. For animation we have to use "position" as keypath.